# How can I scroll automatic text in richTextBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In Form1 constructor I did:

```
richTextBox1.Text = combindedString;
richTextBox1.SelectionStart = 0;
richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
```

combindedString is string.
I want the text in the richTextBox1 to scroll smooth up and then return from bottom over again in a loop nonstop.

But in this case it doesn't move/scroll at all. The text stay still.

This is the format of combindedString:

```
Text test
דווח במקור בתאריך: 12.06.14  שעה : 00:08

Text test1
דווח במקור בתאריך: 12.06.14  שעה : 07:56
```

Maybe this make a problem? This is the combindedString format and also how it look like in the richTextBox1.

Tried this now not working the text stay still:

```
richTextBox1.Text = combindedString;
richTextBox1.SelectionStart = combindedString.Length -1;
richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
```

Comment: You set selection to position `0`, which is default after setting `Text`. You sure `0` is the right value? Perhaps you wanted `combinedString.Length - 1` (to scroll to end) ? And regarding *smooth scrolling* nonstop, it's not what you can do in just constructor, there should be a timer (or background thread, or overdrawn repaint, etc.).

Comment: To expand on what Sinatr said, the `ScrollToCaret()` method just literally scrolls the textbox *immediately* to the caret, not in an animated fashion.  You will need to write code to animate the scrolling.

Comment: Sinatr i tried combinedString.Length - 1 still not working.

Comment: @user3681442 Describe "not working". Is it scrolling? Is there an exception? What is the value of `Length`?